# Excuting an NPM script conditionally based on a bash .sh script

Tags: bash, npm, post, pre

I'm trying to make a `bash` script that asks me a question and, if I respond `y`, executes the subsequent scripts; but, if I respond `n`, it terminates **"ALL"** of the subsequent script.

I already created the bash script, but when I respond with `n`, the following scripts, `build` and `anotherBashScript`, are executed.

**package.json**

```json
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "./ask.sh",
    "build": "vite build",
    "postbuild": "./anotherBashScript.sh"
  },
```

**ask.sh**

```bash
read -p "Are you sure you want to build the app? (y/n) " yn

case $yn in 
    [yY] ) echo Building the app...
        break;;

    [nN] ) echo exiting...;
      
        exit 1;;

    * ) echo invalid response;;
esac
```

Comment: The build script by definition will always follow the prebuild step. A way of achieving what you want is to have a file track the exit code and then wrap the vite build command in another bash script that first checks the file for the exit code before proceeding accordingly.

Comment: @RamanSailopal may you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Raman Sailopal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7840440/raman-sailopal).

I adapted your suggestion and applied it to write the following script, and it was successful!

**package.json**

```json
  "scripts": {
   "prebuild": "./ask.sh",
   "build": "./build.sh",
   "postbuild": "./anotherBashScript.sh"
 },
```

**ask.sh**

```bash
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Are you sure? (y/n) " yn

case $yn in
[yY])
    echo Building the app...
    echo 1 >status.txt
    ;;
[nN])
    echo exiting...
    ;;
*) echo invalid response ;;
esac
```

**build.sh**

```bash
#! /bin/bash

if [[ "$(cat status.txt)" == "1" ]]; then
  yarn run vite build
  echo 1 >status.txt
  exit 1

else
  exit 1
fi
```

**anotherBashScript.sh**

```bash
#! /bin/bash

if [[ "$(cat status.txt)" == "1" ]]; then
      # do stuff
      rm status.txt


else
      exit 1
      rm status.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The build script by definition will always follow the prebuild step. A way of achieving what you want is to have a file track the exit code and then wrap the vite build command in another bash script that first checks the file for the exit code before proceeding accordingly.

Example, using status.txt to track status:

```
   "scripts": {
   "prebuild": "./ask.sh",
   "build": "./build.sh",
   "postbuild": "./anotherBashScript.sh"
 },
```

**ask.sh**

read -p "Are you sure you want to build the app? (y/n) " yn

```
case $yn in 
   [yY] ) echo Building the app...
       break;;

   [nN] ) echo exiting...;
  
       echo 1 > status.txt;;

   * ) echo invalid response;;
 esac
```

**build.sh**

```
 if [[ "$(cat status.sh)" == "1" ]]
 then
       exit 1
 else
       vital build
       if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]
       then
            echo 1 > status.txt
            exit 1
       fi 
  fi
```

**anotherBashScript.sh**

```
if [[ "$(cat status.sh)" == "1" ]]
 then
       exit 1
 else
       ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks,
But your script is flipped.

I used your answer to create it.